# Optimize query with similar fields

Tags: mysql

I have the below schema, fields `owner_id,billing_id,tech_id,admin_id` on `carts` table are pointing to `contacts` table. As you can see from the query result I have to `JOIN` for each field .Is there a way to avoid?

[image]

```
SELECT c.domain, c.period, co.name AS owner, co1.name AS admin, co2.name AS tech, co3.name AS billing, h.nameserver
FROM carts c
LEFT JOIN contacts co ON c.owner_id = co.id
LEFT JOIN contacts co1 ON c.admin_id = co1.id
LEFT JOIN contacts co2 ON c.tech_id = co2.id
LEFT JOIN contacts co3 ON c.billing_id = co3.id
LEFT JOIN HOSTS h ON c.host_id = h.id
WHERE c.user_id =1
```

[image]

Comment: You are only selecting data for one user so it should be pretty fast. Why do you want to avoid the 4 joins?

Comment: I'm asking if there is a better way to query this result. I just want to improve my `SQL` skills.Is there a for loop or a recursive way or a declarative trick to skip this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same results with just one join and pivoting .

```
SELECT c.domain, c.period, h.nameserver,
MAX(CASE WHEN co.id=c.owner_id THEN co.name END) AS owner, 
MAX(CASE WHEN co.id=c.admin_id THEN co.name END) AS admin,
MAX(CASE WHEN co.id=c.tech_id THEN co.name END) AS tech, 
MAX(CASE WHEN co.id=c.billing_id THEN co.name END)  AS billing
FROM carts c
LEFT JOIN contacts co ON co.id IN (c.owner_id , c.admin_id,c.tech_id,c.billing_id)

LEFT JOIN HOSTS h ON c.host_id = h.id
WHERE c.user_id =1
GROUP BY c.domain,c.period,h.nameserver
```

However, check execution plan for both versions, sometimes multiple joins may be faster than such approach.

Comment: I can't figure out how is this working. I see you use `MAX()` how you replace it with a `co.name` shouldn't it be a number?

Comment: it's just pivoting (other RDMS support `PIVOT` keyword to do the same, you can look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table for couple more examples). `CASE` inside `MAX` has default `ELSE NULL` clause.